# AngularJS data binding Form properties in template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple AngularJS app with a single form that has 2 fields on it. I am trying to read the values entered in those 2 fields from my controller but for some reason I am always getting undefined. I have triple checked my code but can't find anything in it, so I hope someone can please help and tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it.

Note: I am using latest AngularJS release 1.2

app.js

```
'use strict';
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','ngSanitize']);
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
       $routeProvider.when('/index', 
                {     templateUrl: 'templates/common/index.html', 
                      controller: 'IndexController'
                }).
                when('/editcontact', 
                {     templateUrl: 'templates/contacts/editContact.html', 
                      controller: 'editContactController'
                }).
                otherwise({redirectTo: '/index'});
}]);
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>myApp</title>
....
....
<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/angular/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/contacts/editContactController.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

editContact.html

```
 <form name="editContactForm">
          <div>
            <fieldset>
              <input id="name" type="text" placeholder=Name..." ng-modal="contacts.name">
              <input id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" ng-modal="contacts.phone">
            </fieldset>

            <button type="submit" ng-click="saveContact(contacts, editContactForm)">Save</button>
            <button type="button" ng-click="cancelEdit()">Cancel</button>
          </div>
         </form>
```

editContactController

```
myApp.controller('editContactController',
        function editContactController($scope){

         $scope.saveContact = function(contacts, editContactForm){
             if(editContactForm.$valid){
                 console.log(contacts.name);                
             }
         };
});
```

Comment: `ng-model` not `modal`carefull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo. **ng-modal** should be **ng-model**

```
<input id="name" type="text" placeholder=Name..." ng-modal="contacts.name">
<input id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" ng-modal="contacts.phone">
```

should be

```
<input id="name" type="text" placeholder=Name..." ng-model="contacts.name">
<input id="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone" ng-model="contacts.phone">
```

Comment: OMG, I can't believe it is this...I spent literary hours on this and never noticed it!!! Thanks a lot for your help!